# PHP A cleaner way of passing button value when the value IS actually 0

Tags: php, html, button

I've had to fudge a piece of code in order for it to work for me. I'm just wondering if I have missed something obvious to clean it up a little, or whether my fudge is in fact the correct way to solve this issue.

I have a button on a page for removing items from a session variable array by their key.

PHP for generating button value....

```
foreach($rows as $key => $row){
++$key;
$sql = 'SELECT ingredient_name FROM ' . INGREDIENTS_TABLE . ' WHERE ingredient_id = '.$row[0];
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$ingredient = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$template->assign_block_vars('ingr_list', array(
    'INGREDIENT'    => $ingredient['ingredient_name'],
    'QTY'       => $row[1],
    'REMOVE_KEY' => $key,
    ));

}
```

HTML button....

```
<button type="submit" name="remove" id="remove" value="{ingr_list.REMOVE_KEY}" title="Remove {ingr_list.INGREDIENT} ?">x</button>
```

PHP for when clicked....

```
if($_POST['remove']){
$key=--$_POST['remove'];
if($key!==false) unset($_SESSION['ingredients'][$key]);
}
```

As you can see I'm getting the $key number and then immediately adding 1 to it. The reason for this is that if the $key value is 0, then the button value is also 0. When the button value is clicked with a value of 0 the if($_POST['remove']) clause is ignored. As soon as the if clause is passed I immediately subtract 1 from it, in order to identify the actual key I am after.

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing because the post value is set, but it's set to 0. `if(0)` is the same as `if(false)` so it does not pass. Try using:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove']))
```

This will cause the code to still only enter on a valid submit, but it will also allow the key to start at 0, without the need to add/subtract 1 as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 0 if you compare by type as well: `if($_POST['remove'] !== false)`.

Comment: That works great also, I've accepted the first answer though.

Comment: Yes, remember this when you use functions that return zero as a valid result (and can return false as well), like `strpos`.